# htaccess 404 not found, redirects, extension masking, Query String

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Good Day,

I have hosted a website at GoDaddy on Linux platform. Below is the folder structure of my website:

- / (root): containing index.php (login page) and logout.php
- Booking: Folder containing many other php
- Admin: Folder containing many other php

After successful login, based on the credentials, the user is redirected to either Booking or Admin.

But I am getting 404 Not Found

Below is the content of .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Set default page for a directory to index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rajiviyer.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rajiviyer.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Currently, the above .htaccess code ensures that any request going to rajiviyer.in will be redirected to www.rajiviyer.in

Also, the default document has been set as index.php

The home page is the login page. After successful login, it redirects into a folder (Booking or Admin). But I am getting 404 not found.

I am trying to: -

- Successful redirect to Booking or Admin or any other folder if I add in the future to the site structure
- Some pages in the Folder have self reference via Query String. What code should I write in .htaccess
- ReWrite URL for folders containing index.php (For example; http://Booking/index.php to http://Booking)

Starting with

Please help. Thanks in advance

Rajiv

Comment: That sounds like you have a code problem. If you are able to get to your site and it happens when you login, your php is doing the redirect and something is not quite right. You also need to include more examples URL's of each kind of redirect you need help with.

Comment: Firstly I am looking for a redirect from domain/index.php to domain/booking/index.php I mean to any of the subfolders of domain i.e domain/subfolder currently there are 2 folders under domain.  They are booking and admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this updated rules and make sure there is an `index.php` in Booking and Admin directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Set default page for a directory to index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rajiviyer.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rajiviyer.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please verify the access permission for the directories and files in it.

> Directories: 755
>
> Static Content: 644
>
> Dynamic Content: 700

Comment: For some reason after adding your code I am getting 403.

Comment: (1) Make sure your login page is redirecting to correct location after authenticating. (2) Make sure there is `index.php` at that location. (3) Verify the access permission for the directory and the `index.php` to which login page is redirected to.